# Why would my route listener suddently load for so long?

Tags: php, performance, session, symfony

I have this odd problem with my symfony add (installed locally)

It was working fine for the past some time, but since yesterday, when I was working on login/logout and a session variable, the load time has **inscresed by a great amound**

Previously, even prior to the image optimization the load time was approx. **500ms**.
Now it's showing me a **1298ms init time**, from which 800ms comes from *initialization*, and according to the Profiler **400ms** comes purely from the `RouterListener`

The side this params are for is around 30mb

Here is the profiler:

[image]

---

The problems started around when I added a change to a session variable in my index controller:

```
$session = $request->getSession();
$session->set('voted', true);
```

And later checked it in the twig with:

```
{% if app.session.get('voted') %}...
```

**The delay happens on all sites, even ones without any session variables**

---

Here are my config files just in case:

**routing.yml**

```
app:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation

oneup_uploader:
    resource: .
    type: uploader

_liip_imagine:
    resource: "@LiipImagineBundle/Resources/config/routing.xml"

logout:
    path: /logout
```

**security.yml**

```
# To get started with security, check out the documentation:
# http://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html
security:

    # http://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#b-configuring-how-users-are-loaded
    providers:
        in_memory:
            memory:
                users:
                    admin:
                        password: kitten
                        roles: 'ROLE_ADMIN'

    firewalls:

        # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        main:
            anonymous: ~

            form_login:
                login_path: login
                check_path: login
            # activate different ways to authenticate


            # http://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#a-configuring-how-your-users-will-authenticate

            # form_login: ~
            # http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/form_login_setup.html
        #secured_area:
            logout:
                path:   /logout
                target: /


    access_control:
            # require ROLE_ADMIN for /admin*
            - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }

    encoders:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext
```

**And also the security controller**. The issue started happening somewhere arount addin the contoller, and the session varialbe

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;


class SecurityController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/login", name="login")
     */
    public function loginAction(Request $request)
    {
        $authenticationUtils = $this->get('security.authentication_utils');

        $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();

        // last username entered by the user
        $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

        return $this->render('security/login.html.twig', array(
            'last_username' => $lastUsername,
            'error'         => $error,
        ));
    }
}
```

---

I really am not sure what else to post here so if more files are needed just tell me.

Has anyone else came across such issue?

How can I fix it?

EDIT: This is **Symfony 3.2.4**

**UPDATE** The website suddently started normally.
Was working on a 404 page, and when I reload it it drops back to **500ms**.

The profiler now looks like this:
[image]

I'm not closing the question, because I yet don't know why would such a change occur suddently

Comment: You can dig dipper using [xhprof](http://php.net/manual/ro/book.xhprof.php) it's a great debugging tool it will tell you about memory consumption and cpu time on the entire trace

Comment: Did you update Symfony? There was an a performance issue with the dev/debug mode with 3.2.3

Comment: @COil Will updating right now not harm my project

Comment: What is the version you are using ? You can test and roll back id there is a problem..

Comment: I actually have 3.2.4

Comment: sorry for that, but did you clear cache and restart your server in between?

Comment: The cache has been cleared many times while the problem occured and did not do much